# Cucumber statistics gem not working

Tags: ruby, automation, rubygems, cucumber, reporting

I am using Cucumber Capybara with Ruby for automation. I have install the cucumber statistics gem for reporting purpose. I have added require 'cucumber_statistics/autoload' in env.rb file. After successful execution of feature file it is showing error as :

undefined method `regexp_source' for #<Cucumber::Glue::StepDefinition:0x0000000293dda0> (NoMethodError)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber_statistics-2.3.0/lib/cucumber_statistics/formatter.rb:29:in`after_step_result'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/formatter/ignore_missing_messages.rb:11:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/ast.rb:117:in`accept'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:580:in `step_invocation'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:543:in`step_invocation'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:387:in `print_step'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:251:in`after_test_step'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:107:in `after_test_step'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:31:in`block in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in`block in broadcast'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in`broadcast'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:40:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:35:in`around_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/around_hook.rb:12:in `describe_to'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:120:in`block (2 levels) in compose_around_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:121:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:121:in`compose_around_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:26:in `block in describe_to'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:19:in`call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:19:in `test_case'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in`describe_to'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:12:in `test_case'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in`describe_to'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:57:in `test_case'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/filters/retry.rb:18:in`test_case'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in `describe_to'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/filters/quit.rb:12:in`test_case'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in `describe_to'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:20:in`block in done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:19:in `map'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:19:in`done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in`done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in`done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:20:in`done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:18:in`done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:24:in `done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:37:in`done'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:32:in `parse'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-core-3.0.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:21:in`compile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:74:in `run!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:33:in`execute!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cucumber-3.0.1/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/cucumber:23:in`load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/cucumber:23:in `'

Ruby version = '2.2.2`
Rails = '4.2.7'
Cucumber = '3.0.1'

Is there any other reporting mechanism that i can use for ruby-cucumber automation?

Comment: it seems that the gem is incompatible with the latest version of Cucumber. If you use Cucumber 2.4.x it will work.

Comment: @Barodapride  After degrading the cucumber version, the gem starts working, but it only shows the count of feature file, steps and scenarios. I m not getting the count of passed and failed scenarios.
Is there any way of getting the passed failed stats ???